# My 8Gb flash drive became a 2,3Mb one

Tags: partitioning, usb, flash, drive

I installed Ubuntu GNOME on my flash drive to re-install it on my computer and it didn't boot. That's okay, I fixed the problem now. But when I formatted my drive to remove the live cd, something happened.

The problem is that after I formatted my flash drive, the amount of gigabits were reduced. When I try to remove a partition from the drive I get an error. Here are some screenshots.

[image: This is my flash drive, seen from Disks]

[image: That's the error I get when trying to delete a partition]

Can someone help me get my 8Gb back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously some sort of error occurred.  I've seen something similar a couple of times.  Often what works best for me is to boot the computer to a live cd and use gparted from that cd to pretend to try to slightly resize any partition.  It seems the action causes gparted to check and adjust its partitions so everything is corrected.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try GParted, but can it modify flash drives (or USB Sticks, if you will)?

Comment: If you go to my bio page, you will learn that NEARLY ALL of my ubuntu installations live on high-performance flash drives, for lack of a better term.  There is no significant difference between them and hard drives except for speed.  Where as most flash drives are slower than rotational hard drives, mine are faster, not to mention portable.